# Property of an Operator.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}) $ given.

Let $T (f(x))=-\partial_t v(x,0)$. Where $v:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$.

$$
\partial_x^2v(x,t)+\partial_t^2v(x,t)=0 ~\in\mathbb{R^2},~~\text{and}~~ v(x,0)= f(x)\in \mathbb{R}.
$$

How can I show $ \int_{\mathbb{R}} T(f(x)) f(x) dx\geq 0$, any hints?

Comment: @hardmath yes you are right, sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The initial value problem
$$
v_{xx}+v_{tt}=0, \quad v(x,0)=f(x) \tag{1}
$$
does not enjoy uniqueness, and hence the operator $Tf=v_t(x,0)$ is not well-defined.

If $v$ is a solution of $(1)$, then so is $\tilde v(x,t)=v(x,t)+at$.

Comment: I agree that the solution of the IVP is not unique.  However the IVP may not be intended as *defining* $T$.  The description of $T$ as an *operator* likely means that, because $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, so too is $T(f)\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$.  This can only be true for (at most) one value of $a$. Whatever the claim to be proven is here, I expect the proof will be "integration by parts".

Comment: Hi, but I am confused then by the first equation in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608640.pdf ? Is this not exactly what I wrote?